# Trying to run ros in 5 days simulation on my computer

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I'm now using the book "ROS in 5 days" to learn the concept of ROS. However, I want to launch the simulation on my own ThinkPad laptop instead of the ROS Development Studio (RDS).
I've download the ROS simulation package from the following website

- http://www.theconstructsim.com/shop/robots/kobuki
- http://www.theconstructsim.com/shop/robots/iri-warm
- http://www.theconstructsim.com/shop/robots/bb-8
- http://www.theconstructsim.com/shop/robots/ardrone/
- http://www.theconstructsim.com/shop/robots/sphero/

While catkin_make them, I faced the fowlloing message

---

```
fred@fred-ThinkPad-X200s:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/fred/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/develfred@fred-ThinkPad-X200s:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/fred/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fred/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 15 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - bb_8_description
-- ~~  - sphero_description
-- ~~  - turtlebot (metapackage)
-- ~~  - turtlebot_gazebo
-- ~~  - sphero_node
-- ~~  - iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory
-- ~~  - iri_wam_aff_demo
-- ~~  - bb_8_teleop
-- ~~  - turtlebot_teleop
-- ~~  - bb_8_gazebo
-- ~~  - iri_wam_description
-- ~~  - iri_wam_gazebo
-- ~~  - kobuki_description
-- ~~  - sphero_gazebo
-- ~~  - turtlebot_description
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_description)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'turtlebot'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_gazebo)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_node)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- sphero_node: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory: 0 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_aff_demo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_aff_demo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_teleop'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_teleop)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_teleop'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_teleop)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_gazebo)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- Found Ogre Ghadamon (1.9.0)
-- Found OGRE: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Volume...
-- Found OGRE_Volume: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Overlay...
-- Found OGRE_Overlay: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'SDF' but neither 'SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'SDF_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_gazebo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kobuki_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/kobuki_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- Found Ogre Ghadamon (1.9.0)
-- Found OGRE: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Volume...
-- Found OGRE_Volume: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Overlay...
-- Found OGRE_Overlay: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:106 (catkin_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'SDF' but neither 'SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'SDF_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:106 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_description)
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) at iri_wam/iri_wam_aff_demo/CMakeLists.txt:116 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "$(catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS)" of target
  "iri_wam_aff_demo_node" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/fred/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _sphero_node_generate_messages_check_deps_SpheroCollision
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target turtlebot_teleop_joy
[  8%] Built target _iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory_generate_messages_check_deps_ExecTraj
[ 12%] Linking CXX shared library /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so
[ 12%] Built target iri_wam_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target iri_wam_gazebo_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target kobuki_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target sphero_gazebo_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 16%] Linking CXX shared library /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3373: recipe for target 'bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4949: recipe for target 'sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed

Install space: /home/fred/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fred/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 15 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - bb_8_description
-- ~~  - sphero_description
-- ~~  - turtlebot (metapackage)
-- ~~  - turtlebot_gazebo
-- ~~  - sphero_node
-- ~~  - iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory
-- ~~  - iri_wam_aff_demo
-- ~~  - bb_8_teleop
-- ~~  - turtlebot_teleop
-- ~~  - bb_8_gazebo
-- ~~  - iri_wam_description
-- ~~  - iri_wam_gazebo
-- ~~  - kobuki_description
-- ~~  - sphero_gazebo
-- ~~  - turtlebot_description
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_description)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'turtlebot'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_gazebo)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_node)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- sphero_node: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory: 0 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_aff_demo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_aff_demo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_teleop'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_teleop)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_teleop'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_teleop)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'bb_8_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(bb8/bb_8_gazebo)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- Found Ogre Ghadamon (1.9.0)
-- Found OGRE: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Volume...
-- Found OGRE_Volume: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Overlay...
-- Found OGRE_Overlay: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'SDF' but neither 'SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'SDF_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:28 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'iri_wam_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iri_wam/iri_wam_gazebo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kobuki_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/kobuki_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sphero_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- Found Ogre Ghadamon (1.9.0)
-- Found OGRE: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Volume...
-- Found OGRE_Volume: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Overlay...
-- Found OGRE_Overlay: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:106 (catkin_package)


CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'SDF' but neither 'SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'SDF_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:106 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(kobuki/kobuki/turtlebot_description)
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) at iri_wam/iri_wam_aff_demo/CMakeLists.txt:116 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "$(catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS)" of target
  "iri_wam_aff_demo_node" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/fred/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/fred/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _sphero_node_generate_messages_check_deps_SpheroCollision
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target turtlebot_teleop_joy
[  8%] Built target _iri_wam_reproduce_trajectory_generate_messages_check_deps_ExecTraj
[ 12%] Linking CXX shared library /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so
[ 12%] Built target iri_wam_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target iri_wam_gazebo_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target kobuki_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 12%] Built target sphero_gazebo_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 16%] Linking CXX shared library /home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3373: recipe for target 'bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/fred/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_sphero_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4949: recipe for target 'sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sphero/sphero/sphero_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sphero_controller.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

---

i've tried install a lot of gazebo package, but it still not working
can any one help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282472/trying-to-run-ros-in-5-days-simulation-on-my-computer/) by [busFred](https://answers.ros.org/users/33666/busfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
you are missing a package in your system. You have not installed the package that provides `gazebo_ros_utils`.
The package that contains that is ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins. You should install everything ROS + Gazebo before trying to use the simulations. That is why we suggest you launch it at the RDS, because everything is configured.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
If the packages have been created properly, and declare all their dependencies, wouldn't a `rosdep install --from-paths /home/fred/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` install everything? Then building should work just fine.